# Firefox plugin to monitor http headers sent to a REST Web service

Tags: java, rest, firefox, http-headers

I have a webapp accessing some REST APIs. Now the REST APIs need some headers to be added to the request. I already have the code for adding the headers in my webapp but i need to verify if it is successfully added in the headers or successfully sent to the REST Web Service. I have no access to the REST Web Service that's why I need to find a way to verify that the headers are correctly set. Maybe a firefox plugin will do. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Use **Firebug** it will show you complete http request and response including headers.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) will solve this for you:

[Firebug Newtowork Monitoring](https://getfirebug.com/network)

There are similar built-in tools in other browsers too (yes, even IE has it nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices to do that. In case you can send your request through jmeter, it has a clean interface to show the request/respone headers and body.

But if you want to send the REST request through your client program, and still want to check the HTTP packet headers and body then Wireshark can be of good help as well.

You may also check the rest client for firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/tamper-data/ to check out the headers, stop the request and even change the header/parameters!

But, you could also just verify with firebug :-)